# Collision avoidance with pointclouds

Tags: drake

I'm working on motion planning for a robotic arm in an environment where I have to ensure collision avoidance. The observation data available to me is in the form of a point cloud representing the scene. I've thought of two potential approaches to tackle this, but I'm unsure which is considered best practice or if there's a better method I haven't considered.

My first idea is to approximate the point cloud using a set of geometry primitives. However, I'm uncertain about the efficiency and accuracy of this method, especially in complex environments.

The second approach involves adding each point in the point cloud to a minimum distance constraint. I'm concerned about the computational load this might entail, especially for dense point clouds.